# Why to have ($ Ax = \lambda x, \langle Ax, x \rangle \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \forall \lambda \geq 0 $), $A$ must be compact and Hermitian?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces

Prove that for a compact Hermitian operator $A$ on a Hilbert space these properties are
equivalent:

(a) $\langle Ax, x \rangle \geq 0$  for all $x$

(b) All eigenvalues of $A$ are nonnegative.

Here's my attempt at the proof:

$a \rightarrow b:$ $\langle Ax, x \rangle \geq 0$ , and $Ax = \lambda x$. Thus, $\langle \lambda x, x \rangle = \lambda ||x||^2\geq 0 \Rightarrow \lambda \geq 0. $
$b \rightarrow a$ : $Ax = \lambda x$ and $\lambda \geq 0 \Rightarrow \langle \lambda x, x \rangle = \lambda ||x||^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow \langle Ax, x \rangle \geq 0.$

But I did not use the fact that $A$ is compact and Hermitian. Where is it necessary for $A$ to be both Hermitian and compact? Did I miss something? Thanks.

Comment: Certainly your second implication is not correct - you assumed $x$ was an eigenvector: (a) is a statement about ALL vectors.

Comment: Oh, now I see. For the second direction, only it can be concluded that $<Av,v> \geq 0$ where $v$ is an eigenvector. But, then how should I approach the second direction for a general $x$? Where to use compactness and Hermitian property of A?

Comment: Perhaps the spectral theorem has something to offer.

Comment: Aha! Thanks. So since A is compact and Hermitian, for $Ax$, we have $Ax = \sum \lambda_i <x,e_i>e_i$. Then forming $<Ax,x>$ yields the result. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compactness is only needed when proving "(b)$\Rightarrow$(a)".

Property (a) says that $A$ is a positive-semidefinite operator, often denoted by $A\geqslant 0$. Their spectra are compact subsets of $\mathbb R_{\geqslant 0}$ which gives (b).

The spectrum of a compact Hermitian operator contains only eigenvalues together with zero (which need not be an eigenvalue). If all these are non-negative, then
"(b)$\Rightarrow$(a)" holds by the spectral theorem for compact operators:
$A= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i\,\langle\,\cdot\,|e_i\rangle\, e_i$